# How to add multiple components to a path

Tags: angular

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    navBarComponent,
    searchBarComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'home', component: navBarComponent},
      {path: 'events', component: navBarComponent},
      {path: 'profile', component: navBarComponent},
      {path: 'organizations', component: navBarComponent},
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ])
  ],
```

I was wondering if there is a simple way to add more than one component to a path. As you can see, I have added a navBarComponent to each of the pages, but I also want to add the searchBarComponent to the homepage as well. I tried separating them by commas and passing it as an array but both methods failed. Please let me know if I'm missing something or if there is an easier way around this.

Comment: If the navbar component should be displayed in every page, you it should be used directly in the template of your root (app) component. A route can only have one component. But of course that component can use as many components it needs to in its template. https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to add the common to root component only if you will use that component in every page rather than adding it on each component.

Answer (score 0):

You can set path variable for your same component and different routes:

```
{path: '#your_scope/:route_name', component: navBarComponent}
```

and every `/#your_scope/what_the_fuck` will route to the navBarComponent.

but by the way. you better just use the navBarComponent in your root component as a template.